# Admob or Adsense for my android apps?

Tags: android

I have 7 apps on the market - all free. In total I have had 10k impressions and have made $11. What do you think of this? Search 'Lewicki' to see my apps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have marginally better outcome with AdSense after switching from Admob. Now - Admob become Google after my switch so I don't know if that holds true. Impressions rate about right based on my experience. To make any sort of decent money with this you need really popular app. Something with 1/2M users (say Angry Birds)

Comment: Alright, I have now graded admob an F. It seems as if the more impressions you get for/with them, the less money you start to make. When I hit my first 10k impressions I made $11. It's now at 40k impressions and I haven't even hit $30. Will try adsense next.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not AdMob specific I'm affraid. In general as you put ads in your app the initial response will be on much larger scale. I guess existing users simply stop reacting to ads after a while. I also recommend to be careful with saturating your app with ads or placing these into prime real estate. Usually it has  opposite effect